# Number of eulerian subgraphs of complete graph

Tags: graph-theory, subgraph

I need an advice on how to approach this problem. It's a part of a project in Graph theory. How to determine a number of eulerian subgraphs of $K_n$ (complete graph with $n$ vertices)? It's part of a project about Cycle space, so I suppose I should approach it this way.

I know every connected even graph is eulerian and vice versa. My first thought was a number of all even subgraphs is due to knowledge from cycle space project part equal to $2^{\mu(G)}$, where $\mu(G)=e(G)-v(G)+\omega(G)$ (cyclomatic number). But those are not neccessarily connected. I am kind of lost, do you think you could help me?

Comment: Indeed you are lost, this forum is for questions in research mathematics, and your question will be closed here. You will find assistance at math.stackexchange.com instead.

Comment: See https://oeis.org/A033678.